# A sequence defined by a single fraction

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

I have a sequence of numbers here, which follow a very simple rule that can be expressed using a single fraction:

> 1, 2, 10, 11, 13, 15, 20, 22, 25, 28, ...

What is this rule (in particular, what is the fraction), and what are the next few numbers in the sequence?

---

Since nobody's gotten it yet, I'll add a few hints over the next little while.

> (06-16 13:22) 1. The numbers in the sequence never get more than 2 digits long.

Comment: Shall we consider 1, 2 as 01, 02?

Comment: @nikamed What would that imply?

Comment: because if it's like this one can find infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @nikamed Can you give me a few examples?

Comment: You can make a number and take every two digits after the point to create your sequence. For example: 0.0102101113152022252831.. leads to a fraction $680486027/66648247604$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You mean the rule can be expressed as a fraction not fraction is the rule.

Comment: Seems like people are stuck. Should I give a hint?

Comment: yes, please....

Comment: you said "The numbers in the sequence never get more than 2 digits long". So is it finite sequence? Also in later sequence will there be decimal numbers?

Comment: @smriti, No, it goes on forever, but you're correct that the sequence stops using decimal digits after a while.

Comment: Wait, it looks like there's some miscommunication here. I think smriti was asking: after a while, will there be decimals (i.e., non-integers)? Whereas I think Joe Z. is saying: after a while, there will be non-decimals (i.e., non-numbers? or maybe all the ones we've seen so far are actually in hex and we start getting A-F as well or something?). Which is *entirely different*.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I see. In that case, to answer both interpretations of the question: the numbers will in fact stay integers, and eventually the numbers will start going into non-decimal digits.

Comment: If the answer I've just given is the intended one, then the bit about non-decimal digits was a *colossal* hint!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yeah, it was almost a complete giveaway, but I had to answer a question somebody asked D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items in the sequence should be numbered from 2 onwards, and then item $b$ is

> the base-$b$ representation of $\displaystyle \left \lfloor \frac{b^2}{4} \right \rfloor$, which can also be written as just $\displaystyle \left \lfloor \frac{100}{4} \right \rfloor$, since $b$ in base $b$ is always $10$.

So the fraction that defines the sequence is

> **100/4**

and the next few entries in the sequence are:

> 30, 33, 37, 3B, 40, 44, 49, 4E, 50.

Comment: (My original answer gave a different fraction and a slightly different -- but equivalent -- explanation. Joe Z has adjusted what I wrote to match his intention.)

Answer (score 3):

1, 2, 10, 11, 13, 15, 20, 22, 25, 28, ...

1, 2, 10, 11, 13, 15, 20, 22, 25, 28, 31, 100, 103, 107, 111, 115, 119, 110, ...

The pattern is explained as follows:

Add (1) to first number (1) time, then add a zero to first number

> 1, 2, 10

Add (1) to new number once

> 11

Add (1+1) to new number (1+1) times, then add a zero to second number

> 13, 15, 20

Add (1+1) to new number once

> 22

Add (1+1+1) to new number (1+1+1) times, then add a zero to third number

> 25, 28, 31, 100

Add (1+1+1) to new number once

> 103

Add (1+1+1+1) to new number (1+1+1+1) times, then add a zero to forth number

> 107, 111, 115, 119, 110

Comment: I don't see any fractions in your definition. Also, you got the next few numbers wrong.